# How to add ChildViewControllers in UITablViewCell correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a tableView with expanded cell.In this expanded cell I have a UIView on top of which I am adding two different `viewControllers`.Now if I add both `viewControllers` I add a `UISegmentControl` to switch between them.However the problem is these `viewControllers` **donot seem to add to `subView` in some cells thus showing a random behaviour.**

Let's see how I am trying to achieve this.

(I am doing UI in XIB.)

1] On cell expansion -> call webservice ->use response to plot data on `viewControllers` and load one or both of `viewControllers`.
2]When expanded cell is removed -> remove the `viewControllers`.

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


if ([self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {


    [self.expandedCells removeObject:indexPath];

    if (lowerVC) { //ViewController1
        [self removeContentController:lowerVC];
    }
    if (upperVC){ //viewController2
        [self removeContentController:upperVC];
    }

    }else{
    isExpanded=YES;
    [self.expandedCells addObject:indexPath]; 

    //call webservice here with completion handler, when completion done, populate viewContollers and add as subView.

      }
      [self.bTableView beginUpdates];
      [self.bTableView reloadData];
      [self.bTableView endUpdates];
    }

   -(void)populateViewControllers{
          //After populating VC's
          [self displayContentController:lowerVC];

   }
```

The methods of adding and removing `viewControllers` is like

```
 -(void)displayContentController:(UIViewController *)content{

   [self addChildViewController:content];
    content.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, expCell.expContainer.frame.size.width, expCell.expContainer.frame.size.height);
     [expCell.expContainer addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];


  }
  -(void)removeContentController:(UIViewController *)VC{

    [VC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [VC.view removeFromSuperview];
    [VC removeFromParentViewController];

 }
```

Comment: It seems like your UI is very complex and my suggestion would be to re-design it. Also why 2 VC inside a expandable cell. What exactly u trying to achieve?

Comment: Separate UIElements like images are be plotted in these View controllers.If both are present.I will switch between the two using segment control.

Comment: For UIElement like images you could use uiimageview to set image's and use a swtich for swtiching between two uiimageview. If any other uielement's are there then logic would depend on other's to for designing your code.

Comment: Actually its not a single image...It can be a set of images.And the second viewController is optional.Depends on webservice response whether or not it should be popuated.

Comment: In that case, don't go for the UI you are working on as it would look complex and messy. Rather you could do a thing is that when user tap a row then move to a another VC with a segmentController and provide your 2 VC over there along with data(set of images) that you want to show.

Comment: I could have, but requirement is different.:-] .I need to show everything in expanded cell.

Comment: Ok then best of luck and don't use two different VC ...just go with one VC along with 2 views in it(controlled by segment controller) that way u might get some less messy and achieve ur goal.

Comment: atleast vote up my comments and your welcome.

Comment: Apparently my reputaion doesn't allow me to ...;-(

Comment: no problem and Still if need anything then let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then best of luck and don't use two different VC ...just go with one VC along with 2 views in it(controlled by segment controller) that way u might get some less messy and achieve ur goal.

So now you could tick my suggest and close this question.